# Cache entries disappears from apc cache even if timeout = 0

Tags: php, zend-framework, apc

I'm working on a page that displays data, some are stored in DB, others are retrieved from an API. To limit aPI calls (I'm limited per day) I store data from the API in a cache entries.
I use APC to cache my Data.

first I check if I have the object in the cache.

```
$cacheEmpty = false;
if (($myData = Zend_Registry::get('MY_ZEND_CACHE')->load("myObject")) === false){
        //I have to use the API
        $cacheEmpty = true;
}
```

Then when I have processed the data, if I have used the API I save the data.

```
  if ($cacheEmpty){
    Zend_Registry::get('MY_ZEND_CACHE')->save($myData, "myObject", array(), 2592000); 
   }
```

I can see that myObject is stored in the cache. But randomly (apparently) myObject disappears from the cache. I have checked the Cache full count that stay at 0. I have always more than 25% free memory. I have searched informations about that issue but nothing has helped me.

Thanks in advance for responding to my question.

Comment: You have a typo on the very first line

Comment: What could be the reason why entries are deleted? The page is actually only used by me and I didn't go on it for 2 days. I thought that only when we get the cached data, the data is deleted if it's too old. am i wrong?